# Git: Rebased to Master. Now what?

Tags: git

Here's my workflow from today:

```
  app: $ git branch
  global-nav-text
* master
  thrills-popUp
  app: $ git checkout thrills-popUp
Switched to branch 'thrills-popUp'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/thrills-popUp'.
  app: $ git status
On branch thrills-popUp
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/thrills-popUp'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ngrok
    simple-cors-http-server.py

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
  app: $ git branch
  global-nav-text
  master
* thrills-popUp
  app: $ git checkout global-nav-text
Switched to branch 'global-nav-text'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/global-nav-text'.
  app: $ git rebase master
Current branch global-nav-text is up to date.
  app: $ git checkout thrills-popUp
Switched to branch 'thrills-popUp'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/thrills-popUp'.
  app: $ git status
On branch thrills-popUp
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/thrills-popUp'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ngrok
    simple-cors-http-server.py

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
  app: $ git branch
  global-nav-text
  master
* thrills-popUp
  app: $ git rebase master
Current branch thrills-popUp is up to date.
  app: $ git commit -am "Coda seems to have junked up my code. Specifically JS. The app wasn't pulling in both parks. Turns out that Coda (or something) changed 'append(newRow)' to 'append(ReturnedwRow).' There was an error from Coda after I rebased the global-nav-text branch to master. I updated the JS and all is working well now."
[thrills-popUp 737b135] Coda seems to have junked up my code. Specifically JS. The app wasn't pulling in both parks. Turns out that Coda (or something) changed 'append(newRow)' to 'append(ReturnedwRow).' There was an error from Coda after I rebased the global-nav-text branch to master. I updated the JS and all is working well now.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
  app: $ git push --all
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 495 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://qfrank@bitbucket.org/uoix/14-03157-front-gate-sales-mat.git
   bb79a23..737b135  thrills-popUp -> thrills-popUp
  app: $ git status
On branch thrills-popUp
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/thrills-popUp'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ngrok
    simple-cors-http-server.py

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
  app: $ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
  app: $ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
  app: $ git checkout thrills-popUp
Switched to branch 'thrills-popUp'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/thrills-popUp'.
  app: $ git checkout thrills-popUp
Already on 'thrills-popUp'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/thrills-popUp'.
```

I thought once I `rebase` that it would "merge" my branches into `master`. I was wrong.

I assumed (after `rebase`) that when I ran `git branch` I would only see the `master` and none of the branches.

Here's what I had:

```
        o------o------o------o------o------o thrills-popUp
       /
-----o------o------o master
  \
   o------o------o global-nav-text
```

I eventually deleted 'global-text-nav' (but it's still in my remote repo).

My intention was to merge all branches into the master both locally and remotely.

How do I do this without messing anything up?

I've been reading about `pull`, `merge`, `rebase`, `fetch`, etc. But I find it a bit confusing.

Here's what I was trying to accomplish:

```
       o------o------o------o------o------o thrills-popUp
      /                                    \
-----o------o-------o-------o-------o-------o------o master
   \               /
    o------o------o global-nav-text
```

But since I deleted "global-nav-text" locally I'm OK with doing this:

```
       o------o------o------o------o------o thrills-popUp
      /                                    \
-----o-------o-------o-------o------o-------o------o master
```

I don't want to download the remote repo and mix it with my local one. Don't want to cause any screw ups.

I would like to just "cleanly" merge my remaining branch, and have my remote repo look like my local repo.

Also, I see all the commits on my remote repo but none of the new HTML, CSS, and JS files I've added locally. I see the initial files that were uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `git merge` is what you're looking for.

This should do what you're trying to accomplish.

```
git pull
git fetch origin
git checkout master
git merge thrills-popUp
git merge global-nav-test
git push
```

It would first fetch the remote repository so that you download the branch you previously deleted, then go on branch master and merge the other two into master. Then push the changes to the remote repo.

Comment: @Protector It worked. When I run `git branch` I get master & thrills-popUp. When I `checkout` master my app doesn't work right. But when I `checkout` thrills-popUp, it's back to where it should be. Should I keep working from that branch instead of the master? Should I rebase thrills-popUp to master? How come thrills-popUp doesn't show up on my remote repo? What's the best thing to do?

Comment: @FrankDraws Why do you use `git branch` at all after this ? Because I creates a new branch. If you want to go in a branch, use `git checkout branchName`.

If you want to merge `thrills-popUp` into `master` again, do `git checkout master` then `git merge thrills-popUp`

Comment: `git branch` will list all the branches and highlight the branch that's in current use. It won't create one. Again, I really appreciate your time. I've learned a lot. Good times.